# How do I add a border over this heading and paragraph element?

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to add a border around a heading and paragraph element but it is not working. These elements are inside of a div but yet the border does not form. How do I fix this?

```css
.box1{
    
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: absolute;
}

.WorldWideWeb{
    left: 80px;
    top: 135px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
}

.worldwidewebp{
    left: 80px;
    top: 185px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 70ch;
}
```

```html
<div class= "box1">
<h2 class="WorldWideWeb">Introduction to the World Wide Web (WWW)</h2>
<p class="worldwidewebp"><u>What is the Web and how does it work?</u><br>blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, it works all right.  Notice that little dot in the top left corner?  That's your box.  Try removing the position:absolutes.  They're ... well, not evil, but generally misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute` from heading and paragraph.

```css
.box1{
    display: block;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: absolute;
}

.WorldWideWeb{
    left: 80px;
    top: 135px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
}

.worldwidewebp{
    left: 80px;
    top: 185px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    max-width: 70ch;
}
```

```html
<div class= "box1">
<h2 class="WorldWideWeb">Introduction to the World Wide Web (WWW)</h2>
<p class="worldwidewebp"><u>What is the Web and how does it work?</u><br>blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've removed position: absolute from your code and it works.
If you are using position absolute, make sure you have a parent with position: relative. Also, try to avoid nesting elements with position: absolute inside other absolutes. That's just unnecessary in most cases.